# Can I call optional::emplace as a member initializer?

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to add a new constructor an existing class and wondering if I can somehow do an `emplace` initialization of an `optional` and then use that value in the initializer for another member value.

For example:

```cpp
class sample {
    my_type sc;
    optional<opt_type> run;

    sample() :
        sc( gen_default() ) {
    }

    enum ctor_alt { ctor_alt };
    sample( ctor_alt ) :
        emplace( run, ctor_arg ), /* Possible somehow? */
        sc( run.field ) {
    }
```

My primary motivation is that I don't want to alter the type of `my_type`. There are many users of this variable and putting it in a wrapper would require changing a lot of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure thing, just call the [constructor of `std::optional`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/optional) with `std::in_place_t`:

```
run{std::in_place, ctor_arg}
```

[`std::in_place_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/in_place) is a tag type to disambiguate when you want the type to construct the value in place instead of copying it.

If you want to use the value of the optional for another member variable, you need to make sure that that member variable comes *after* the optional, because member objects are initialized in the order that they appear.

Answer (score 5):

`emplace` is a member function, and you cannot execute a member function until you've constructed the object (unless you're the object's constructor). But if you want to construct an engaged `optional<T>` in-place, you can simply use the `std::in_place` constructor:

```
run( std::in_place, ctor_arg )
```

However, member initializers are always executed in the order in which the *members are declared*, not the order in the member initializer list (your compiler ought to warn you if you initialize them out of order). So if you want to use an earlier initializer to initialize a later variable, you have to order them correctly in your declarations:

```
optional<opt_type> run;
my_type sc;
```